# Program outputs a lot of warnings and an error by using QWebEngineView. How to fix?

Tags: qt

When I use QWebEngineView to display a web page, the program outputs a lot of warnings and an error. Please tell me how to resolve these warnings and errors.

webview.cpp

```
#include "webview.h"

webview::webview(QWidget *parent) : QWebEngineView(parent)
{

}

webview::~webview()
{

}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "webview.h"
#include <QFile>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    webView = new webview(this);
    webView->load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
    webView->resize(1024, 750);

   // webView->show();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.resize(1024, 750);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Here's the output.

```
js: Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'unload'.
[18236:18132:1023/152811.537:ERROR:render_process_impl.cc(281)] WebFrame LEAKED 1 TIMES
js: The Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy header has been ignored, because the URL's origin was untrustworthy. It was defined either in the final response or a redirect. Please deliver the response using the HTTPS protocol. You can also use the 'localhost' origin instead. See https://www.w3.org/TR/powerful-features/#potentially-trustworthy-origin and https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-cross-origin-opener-policy-header.
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D11Device::CreateInputLayout: The provided input signature expects to read an element with SemanticName/Index: 'TEXCOORD'/2 and component(s) of the type 'int32'.  However, the matching entry in the Input Layout declaration, element[2], specifies mismatched format: 'R16G16_UINT'.  This is not an error, since behavior is well defined: The element format determines what data conversion algorithm gets applied before it shows up in a shader register. Independently, the shader input signature defines how the shader will interpret the data that has been placed in its input registers, with no change in the bits stored.  It is valid for the application to reinterpret data as a different type once it is in the vertex shader, so this warning is issued just in case reinterpretation was not intended by the author. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #391: CREATEINPUTLAYOUT_TYPE_MISMATCH]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D11Texture2D1::SetPrivateData: Existing private data of same name with different size found! [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #55: SETPRIVATEDATA_CHANGINGPARAMS]
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D11Texture2D1::SetPrivateData: Existing private data of same name with different size found! [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #55: SETPRIVATEDATA_CHANGINGPARAMS]
D3D11 WARNING: Process is terminating. Using simple reporting. Please call ReportLiveObjects() at runtime for standard reporting. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING: Live Producer at 0x000001B01287FEE0, Refcount: 40. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001B0128C7F20, Refcount: 3. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001B012BE1690, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001B012B77BF0, Refcount: 2. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001B012B2C480, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001B012B2DAD0, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001B012BC4A80, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001B00938A610, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
...
D3D11 WARNING: Live                         Object :    159 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
```

I would like to fix these errors and warnings, please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Does this happens on startup while loading the url you set? Note that the http protocol is largely considered deprecated for security concerns (some browsers already have or are going to disable its support). If, after properly changing that url, you still receiving the rest of the errors then please add more details about the url(s) giving the errors, the Qt version and the whole OS environment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice! When I changed the qt version from 6.5.2 to 5.15.2 the error as well as the warning was eliminated.